# Spring Boot in Intellij Idea ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer works only as a separate class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot

In Intellij Idea, when I run a SpringBoot Run task, it compiles the project successfully if I have two separate classes, the one is

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EnrollappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EnrollappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and another one is

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(EnrollappApplication.class);
    }

}
```

But when I try to do

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EnrollappApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(EnrollappApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EnrollappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

it gives me an error

```
2017-06-05 13:17:23.196  WARN 16240 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [ua.com.mobrada.EnrollappApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
2017-06-05 13:17:23.211 ERROR 16240 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception
```

Can anyone explain me why does this happen?

Comment: Why do you need the `SpringBootServletInitializer` are you going to deploy it as a war? If not you aren't going to need it. Make sure you have all the same versions of jars of Spring Boot. You are using the devtools which might (and will) complicate things.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes, I need to make a war package of it. Actually, if I do 'extends SpringBootServletInitializer' for the main class and will Override the SpringApplicationBuilder in the main class and then will do 'mvn clean package', I will get no errors and my war package deploys to a tomcat8.5 well, then. But, if I compile that latter option in Intellij Idea, it gives me these errors.

Comment: It has nothing to do with compiling from command line or not it has to do with the fact you are using Spring Boot Devtools.